# create custom textview and set drawable to right of it

Tags: android, textview, android-custom-view

Hi I create custom textview which we have set font to it
this is my custom textview class

```
public class mTextView extends TextView {
private int CircleColor=0;

// Default constructor when inflating from XML file
public mTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
    init(attrs);
}
private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
    //setIncludeFontPadding(false);
    if(attrs!=null){
        TypedArray a=getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.mTextView);
        String font=a.getString(R.styleable.mTextView_mt_font);
        if(font!=null) {

            Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), font);
            setTypeface(typeface);
        }
    }
}

// Default constructor override
public mTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(attrs);


        setGravity(getGravity() | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL); //make sure that the gravity is set to the top

}
}
```

and it works fine but when I set drawable to the right of textview my textview do not show my drawable

```
 <tools.mTextView
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            app:mt_font="fonts/irterafik.ttf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/registerdata"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="registerdata"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

so can anyone help about this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems It's because you have the gravity set to right. Try to remove it and see if the problem solved